# Automatic reconnection from IBM MQ consumer issue

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Application is connecting to IBM MQ queue and there is a consumer attached to it. But recently, we encountered a situation/failover which we did not think while writing the code. Recently Queue Manager went down for couple of minutes due to some reason and when it got brought back, consumers of our application got detached from queue.

Only way to attach it back was to restart the application again manually. Code snippet looks like this :-

```
protected void initalizeConnection() {
    try {
        MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName(System.getProperty(IBMMQ_HOSTNAME));
        int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty(IBMMQ_PORT));
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        connectionFactory
            .setQueueManager(System.getProperty(IBMMQ_QUEUEMANAGER));
        connectionFactory.setChannel(System.getProperty(IBMMQ_CHANNEL));

        // For a connection to a queue manager in client mode
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        QueueConnection connection =
            connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session =
            connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination =
            session.createQueue(IBM_MQ_SUBC_DESTINATION_NAME_COMPLETE_LOAD);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        consumer.setMessageListener(closedLoadListener);
    } catch (JMSException jmsException) {
        LOG.error("Error in registering consumer with IBM MQ",
            jmsException);
    }
}
```

> Question :- I want to know if there is any configuration settings
>   which i can put at connectionfactory level or some other way by which
>   auto reconnect option is enabled at consumer level ?

Note :- I have tried adding following code also

```
connectionFactory.setClientReconnectOptions(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
connectionFactory.setClientReconnectTimeout(1200);
```

but unfortunately, this also did not work.

Comment: You said the queue manager went down, was this a crash of the server or was it shutdown by a MQ admin?  If by a MQ admin, for reconnect to work they have to include the `-r` flag on the `endmqm` command, for instance `endmqm -r QMGRNAME`.  If the queue manager crashes or you are disconnected because of a network issue the reconnect will also work.

Comment: it was shut down by MQ admin. I checked with him and he had started with -i option. Would there be any side-effects of using -r in place of -i?

Comment: He could use `-ir`

Comment: Let me know if it works when shutdown with -ir and I'll post a answer.

Comment: Did you ever test this and if so did it solve the problem?